# Where put XML attribute declarations in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have a complex element with children and those children have attributes. Everything works fine, but now I needed to add an attribute for the complex main element.

This was the code I had which worked fine:

```
<xs:element name="route">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="origin">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="name"/>
        <xs:attribute name="category">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="1sub1sub1"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="2sub1sub1"/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

So how do I add an attribute to the route element? If I do it like this, it outputs an error that the attribute is not allowed int his context:

```
<xs:element name="route">
<xs:complexType>
 <xs:attribute name="foobar"/>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="origin">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="name"/>
        <xs:attribute name="category">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="1sub1sub1"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="2sub1sub1"/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute declarations as the ***last*** declarations ***within*** `xs:complexType`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="route">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="origin">
          <xs:complexType>

            <!-- WITHOUT child elements-->
            <!-- Add attribute declarations here -->
            <xs:attribute name="name"/>
            <xs:attribute name="category">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:enumeration value="1sub1sub1"/>
                  <xs:enumeration value="2sub1sub1"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>

          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>

      <!-- WITH child elements-->
      <!-- Add attribute declarations here -->
      <xs:attribute name="foobar"/>

    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```